# How can I decode a byte array using a JpegBitmapDecoder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap, imagesource

I cannot decode images back from their encoded form as a (Jpeg) byte array retrieved from my database to be used as image sources for my WPF application.

The code I am using to encode them as a Jpeg byte array is as follows:

```
public byte[] bytesFromBitmap(BitmapImage bit)
    {
        byte[] data;
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bit));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return data;

    }
```

This is taking my Image taken directly from a webpage and assigned to an Image control like so:

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(entity.Image.ImageSrc)); //the entity has been saved in my DB, having been parsed from html
pbImage.Source = img;
```

This works just fine, I encode the BitmapImage and it saves just fine. But when I retrieve it from the DB and try to display it in another window, I cannot get it to work after trying every example I can see online - all either render nothing, or a black box or a visual mess not at all similar to the image I encoded.

Neither of the following have worked for me:

```
public BitmapSource GetBMImage(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource frame = decoder.Frames[0];

            return frame;

        }
    }

 public static BitmapImage ImageFromBytes(byte[] imageData)
    {
        if (imageData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                mem.Position = 0;
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.UriSource = null;
                image.StreamSource = mem;
                image.EndInit();
            }
            image.Freeze();
            return image;
        }
    } //this throws a 'No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found' exception
```

Among other uses of memory streams and decoders I just can't get this to work - can anyone help?

Comment: first, could you confirm the bytes saved to DB and the bytes read from DB are identical?

Comment: And you did not make use of the `imageData` at all in `ImageFromBytes` method.

Comment: The most likely way to subtly corrupt a byte[] with a database is to save it as a string.  That can't work, not all byte values are character codes.  You'll need to encode it with Convert.ToBase64String().  Or better yet, change the dbase column type.